# CakePHP Error Database not defined

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I searched in every question an answer to this, but nothing found!
This is the error when I enter in localhost/cakephp:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: datasource [CORE\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 258]
```

The other error:

```
Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.
```

Datasource class could not be found.

This is my config in database.php:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
var $default = array('driver' => 'mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                 'database' => '',
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'lorizz',
                     'password'    => 'reyxD22!',
                     'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
                     'prefix'      => '');

var $test = array('driver' => 'mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                  'database' => '',
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'lorizz',
                     'password'    => 'reyxD22!',
                     'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
                     'prefix'      => '');

}
?>
```

Any answer?

Comment: What is the location of the file, and what is the location of APP?

Comment: Are you sure it is in the correct location (in the Config directory in you application folder)? It may be case sensitive.

Comment: Yes it's in cakephp -> APP -> Config

Comment: `public $Mysql = array([...]` ? It says it cant find connection "Mysql", so have you defined "Mysql" ?

Comment: ah it's public $default = array([...]

Comment: now I got this error: "The datasource configuration "default" was not found in database.php"

Comment: Just to make sure, that file is database.php not database.example.php isn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you need to remove database used twice in your variables 
var $default and var $test

the config in database.php should be :

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
var $default = array('driver' => 'mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'lorizz',
                     'password'    => 'reyxD22!',
                     'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
                     'prefix'      => '');

var $test = array('driver' => 'mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'user',
                     'password'    => 'password!',
                     'database'    => 'test_database_name',
                     'prefix'      => '');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

only change 'driver' => 'mysql', to 'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
public $default = array('datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                 'database' => '',
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'lorizz',
                     'password'    => 'reyxD22!',
                     'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
                     'prefix'      => '');

public $test = array('datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                  'database' => '',
                     'host'        => 'localhost',
                     'login'       => 'lorizz',
                     'password'    => 'reyxD22!',
                     'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
                     'prefix'      => '');

}
?>
```

Comment: set database name and see the solution.