# CakePhp MySql PDO connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I am newbie with CakePhP framework. I am up to develop a demo website using same framework. I am getting this error on app home page:

CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.

Datasource class Mysql could not be found.

i read number of posts on google and stack overflow and checked my database connection using PDO, here is the URL where i checked database connection using PDO: http://hope4gud.com/test.php

And this is where i am trying to configure my app:

http://hope4gud.com/cakephp/

Thank You
Vikas S.

Comment: class DATABASE_CONFIG {

 public $default = array(
  'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'login' => 'hope4gud_cake',
  'password' => '',
  'database' => 'hope4gud_cake',
  'schema' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'encoding' => 'utf8',
 );

 public $test = array(
  'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'login' => 'hope4gud_cake',
  'password' => '',
  'database' => 'hope4gud_cake',
  'schema' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'encoding' => 'utf8',
 );
}

Comment: I think, you are going to need to post some code here. We can't see what is going wrong without it. Don't post the it with your passwords though.

Comment: thanks sarcoma, i have configured database.php as follow:

Comment: Ok, so you have already posted your password, just make sure you change it, probably best to change all the sensitive details when you use this in production.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this error occur even after i have configured everything right?

Comment: What is the difference between test.php and cakephp/ do they both have access to the Database config?

Comment: test.php is having mysql pdo code just to check server is PDO supported and database connection is eastablished successfully.

Comment: and hope4gud/cakephp/ is actual app route where the app to be configured

Comment: But in test you can access the DB with pdo?

Comment: yes in test DB is with PDO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333955/cakephp-error-database-not-defined

Comment: It looks like you have the database defined twice, when they should be different.

Comment: it is solved as i did not change my file name to 'MyDatasource.php'

Comment: Glad you got there in the end